# SQL Server temporary tables with a key in different sessions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, primary-key, temp-tables

In a stored procedure, I use a temporary table with a primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
(
    [RowId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Id] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE #tmpTable 
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_NamePK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (RowId);
```

The procedure works, but if I run the same procedure in another session I get an error

> 'PK_NamePK already exists'

How to use keys or indexes on temporary tables so that they are visible only in their scope?

Comment: 1) Don't name it (declare it in the definition/let the DB do it). 2) Create a proper table, not a temp one. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   CREATE TABLE #tmpTable
   (
        [RowId] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        [Id] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL
    )
```

There is no need to add alter table, you can define by table creation. Hope this work, I have never tried to add primary key on temptable before.